# How can I properly achieve atomic actions over Firestore in c#

Tags: .net, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I'm trying to implement a simple queue over Firestore (I know Google Cloud Task exists, but in my use case, I can only use Firestore).

My requirements include handling a multi-worker case so I need to read the queue and taking ownership of a task will be atomic.

This is my c# code:

```
private async Task<Massage?> ValidateMsg(DocumentSnapshot? docSnap)
{
    if (docSnap == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Do transactions to make sure all of our data is in check
    Massage? res = await _db.RunTransactionAsync(async transaction =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[ValidateMsg] Transaction start with referance: {docSnap.Reference}");

        // Read the specific doc again
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.GetSnapshotAsync(docSnap.Reference);
        Console.WriteLine($"[ValidateMsg] Transaction Read finished");


        // If we got here == we have a massage in the queue
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = snapshot.ToDictionary();
        dict["Id"] = docSnap.Id;
        Massage? msg = new Massage(dict);

        //Console.WriteLine($"[ValidateMsg] Found msg: {msg.Msg} with the id: {docSnap.Id}, ttl: {msg.Ttl} retryes: {msg.Retries} and owner: {msg.Owner}");

        // Did we rich max retries for this msg?
        if (msg.Retries == c_maxRetries)
        {
            await ClearFailed(msg);
            msg = null;
            //Console.WriteLine($"[ValidateMsg] End");
            Console.WriteLine($"[ValidateMsg] Transaction end");

            return null;
        }

        // Set ourselves as the owners and set the ttl
        Dictionary<string, object> updates = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Owner", c_workerName},
            { "Ttl",  DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(c_ttl) },
            { "Retries", msg.Retries + 1 }  // Update retries
        };
        
        Console.WriteLine($"[ValidateMsg] Old ttl:{msg.Ttl} New:{updates["Ttl"]}, googleVers:{Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(c_ttl))}");
        // Update the document
        transaction.Update(docSnap.Reference, updates);

        Console.WriteLine($"[ValidateMsg] Transaction end");
        return msg;
    });

    return res;
}

private async Task<DocumentSnapshot?> GetPotentialMsgAsync()
{
    DocumentSnapshot? docSnap = (await _db.Collection(c_queue).WhereEqualTo("Owner", null).Limit(1).GetSnapshotAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
    if (docSnap == null)
    {
        // Try get a msg based on Ttl
        docSnap = (await _db.Collection(c_queue).WhereLessThan("Ttl", Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow)).Limit(1).GetSnapshotAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
        if (docSnap == null)
        {
            // No message to process
            return null;
        }
    }

    return docSnap;
}

public async Task<Massage?> GetAsync()
{
    Massage? msg = null;
    DocumentSnapshot? potential = await GetPotentialMsgAsync();
    while (msg == null && potential != null)
    {
        msg = await ValidateMsg(potential);
        if (msg == null)
        {
            potential = await GetPotentialMsgAsync();
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"[GetAsync] Found msg: {msg.Msg} with the id: {msg.Id}, ttl: {msg.Ttl} retries: {msg.Retries} and owner: {msg.Owner}");
    return msg;
}
```

The idea, there is no atomic collection operation, only atomic document, so I will attempt to get a document that I need to handle and then inside a transaction (which should be atomic) I will validate that this document is indeed not taken, and will update that I'm the owner of this msg.

When I tested the above code I got this output:

```
[ValidateMsg] Transaction start with referance: projects/****/databases/(default)/documents/queue/0
[ValidateMsg] Transaction start with referance: projects/****/databases/(default)/documents/queue/0
[ValidateMsg] Transaction start with referance: projects/****/databases/(default)/documents/queue/0
[ValidateMsg] Transaction start with referance: projects/****/databases/(default)/documents/queue/0
[ValidateMsg] Transaction start with referance: projects/****/databases/(default)/documents/queue/0
[ValidateMsg] Transaction Read finished
[ValidateMsg] Transaction Read finished
[ValidateMsg] Transaction Read finished
[ValidateMsg] Old ttl:01/01/0001 0:00:00 New:02/11/2023 7:51:52, googleVers:Timestamp: 2023-11-02T07:51:52.517886Z
[ValidateMsg] Old ttl:01/01/0001 0:00:00 New:02/11/2023 7:51:52, googleVers:Timestamp: 2023-11-02T07:51:52.517885200Z
[ValidateMsg] Old ttl:01/01/0001 0:00:00 New:02/11/2023 7:51:52, googleVers:Timestamp: 2023-11-02T07:51:52.517923900Z
[ValidateMsg] Transaction end
[ValidateMsg] Transaction end
[ValidateMsg] Transaction end
[ValidateMsg] Transaction Read finished
```

As you can see, this is obviously non-atomic operations and there is a serious multi-threading issue here...
What do I do rung?